# Regression with an intervention with delayed effect on the outcome

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

Suppose we follow the number of visits of a hospital during a certain time. At a defined date a policy changes (intervention) and we would like to know if the policy has an effect on the number of visits (see figure: $y2$ is number of visites, $t$ is time, the arrow shows the start of the intervention, dashed red line are *true* values).

[image]

There is one problem:

  - 
  the effect of the intervention is delayed and fullfilled at an unknown time.

With other words: time of delay is a random variable which has to be estimated itself.

To simplify the problem lets assume that

  - number of visits before ($pre$) and after ($post$) the intervention on the long term are constant but at different levels

  - the change from start of the intervention (old level of the number visits) to the new level of number of visits is linear ($trans$).

What follows is the code in R to simulate the graphic above.

```
# 50 Time points
t <- 1:50

# intervention starts at 21
start <- 21
p <- factor(rep(c("prev","post"),c(start-1,30)), levels=c("prev","post"))

# The effect of intervention is delayed and increases continuously
# Here I make a strong assumption: linear increase
# -> The time of the full effect of the intervention is randomly
(delay <- floor(runif(1,5,15)))

# Counts y:
y <- NA

# Until t=20 it is y = 10
(y <- ifelse(t <  start, 10, NA))

# At the full effect of the intervention it is y = 15
(y <- ifelse(t >= start + delay , 15, y))

# Linear increase of the effect of the intervention
(y <- ifelse(t >= start & t < start + delay, 10 + 5/delay*(t-start), y))

# Add an error
y2 <- y + rnorm(length(y))

# Plot
plot(t,y2,type="b", ylim=c(0,20))
lines(t,y, lty=2, col="red")
legend("topleft",legend=c("Random","Exact"), lty=c(1,2),
       col=c("black","red"), pch=c(1,NA))

arrows(21,5,21,9, length=0.1)
text(21,4,"Start intervention")

arrows(32,18,32,15.5, length=0.1)
text(32,19,"Full effect of intervention\n(random)")
```

If the time of delay were known I could just bild a vector with 3 levels for each period *pre*, *trans*, *post*. In the example above delay was 11:

```
v <- factor(c(rep("prev",20),rep("trans",11), rep("post",19)), 
              levels=c("prev","trans","post"))
```

Fit the data with time and period-vector:

```
summary(lm(y2 ~ t*v))
```

gives the following result:

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  10.49412    0.49640  21.140  < 2e-16 ***
t            -0.01587    0.04144  -0.383 0.703567    
vtrans      -10.77554    2.71440  -3.970 0.000262 ***
vpost         2.95846    1.91683   1.543 0.129892    
t:vtrans      0.52777    0.10999   4.798 1.87e-05 ***
t:vpost       0.04638    0.06100   0.760 0.451099
```

All the cofficients makes sense.

I would like to know which model would be appropriate if the length of delay (= transition phase) is random.

Any idea?